# Convert ngFor to @for in angular

Tags: html, angular

i'm currently trying to adapt my code to use the new features of angular 17, but i've got a problem with converting some stuff in the html.

So i have this field that retrieves the nationalities and sets the value to them

```
<mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Nationality</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="nationality">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let nationality of nationalities" [value]="nationality">
                {{ nationality }}
              </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

And this is a snippet of how i've had it before

```
<mat-option value="English">English</mat-option>
<mat-option value="German">German</mat-option>
<mat-option value="Spanish">Spanish</mat-option>
<mat-option value="Italian">Italian</mat-option>
<mat-option value="French">French</mat-option>
```

But i can't find a way so i can use @for instead of ngFor. I'm new to angular so, sorry if the question is stupid.
Thank you!

Comment: In this case, I don't think you should use the new syntax, because it is more readable now IMO. `*ngFor` is not being replaced; there is just an extra way now to do it.  However, you state, that you cannot find a way to do it using the new syntax, but I'm curious about what you have tried.

Comment: This lets me select the nationalities but the problem is with value, because that is mandatory
            `@for(nationality of nationalities; track nationality){
                <mat-option>{{nationality}}</mat-option>
            }`

Comment: And i cant do something like this ` [value]="nationality"` to set the value like i did with ngFor

Comment: You can also track by index: `@for(nationality of nationalities; track $index){..}`, and if you need store the index in a variable `@for(nationality of nationalities;let i=$index;track i){..}`

Comment: @Eliseo Thank you, this might be usefull in some other parts of the project, but in this case i need to set the value as the nationality.

Comment: The value are in both case `nationality` (or if is an object can be, e.g. `nationality.id`). It' s only that we can use the "index" as "track"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new syntax is not that hard. Here's how you can use the new syntax instead of the old one:

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Nationality</mat-label>
  <mat-select formControlName="nationality">
    @for (nationality of nationalities; track nationality) {
      <mat-option [value]="nationality">
        {{ nationality }}
      </mat-option>
    }
    <!-- you could add @empty if needed -->
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I strongly suggest you read the documentation about it here: [angular.dev Documentation](https://angular.dev/api/core/@for#mat-tab-content-88-0)

Comment: Thank you very much, with your answer i've found where i've made the mistake.